# Sharing foler in multiple docker container docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm using volumes to share folder in multiple docker container but it not work. I wanna access folder `/usr/src/app` of web container inside filebeat container. When I access filebeat container it not have folder in `/usr/src/app`.  Here is my docker-compose file

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    container_name: test-app
    working_dir: /usr/src/app
    command: /bin/bash startup.sh
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: .
        target: /usr/src/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - logs
  filebeat:
    build:
      context: ./filebeat
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: test-filebeat
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: .
        target: /usr/src/app
    depends_on:
      - web
    networks:
      - logs

networks:
  logs:
    driver: bridge
volumes:
  app-volume:
```

Where is my wrong? Please help me

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use:

```
volumes:
      - /full/path/folder:/usr/src/app
```

and remove :

```
volumes:
  app-volume:
```

since you do not use it.

Comment: Can you explain this answer to me?

Comment: I assumed your working directory  `.` contains files and folders . So you need to specify wich folder you want to mount.  And the last volume section you used will create a named volume which is not used nowhere in your compose file